# SharePoint 2013 Permissions modal dialogs are blank

Tags: 2013

I've got a SharePoint 2013 farm that regularly shows blank modal popups including the permissions dialog, add a page, etc. The farm has custom branding, but I've demonstrated that even unbranded pages within the farm have this problem. Any ideas?

Comment: I am assuming that you have been able to demonstrate that on a new Site Collection/Web App without any branding enabled, correct?